# Writing an Euler integrator for a dropped object with drag

Tags: python

I am trying to write an Euler integrator to calculate the time, velocity, position and acceleration of a dropped object subject to aerodynamic drag.  I can't seem to construct a working loop that updates the values and appends them to their data arrays correctly.  I apologize for the beginner question but help would be appreciated.

m and g are already defined.

```
import numpy as np
# create new arrays
Adat = [0]  #acceleration
Vdat = [0]  #velocity
Zdat = [0]  #height


V0 = 0
Vdat[0] = V0        #set initial conditions

Z0 = 30000
Zdat[0] = Z0

T = 0

t_step = 0.9  #set time step in seconds

b = 0.5  #drag coefficient in kg/s

while Zdat[-1] >= 0:
    A1 = (-m*g-b*np.abs(V0)*V0)/m
    V1 = V0+A1*t_step
    Z1 = Z0+V1*t_step
    T = T + t_step
    Adat.append(A1)
    Vdat.append(V1)
    Zdat.append(Z1)
    V0 = V1
    Z0 = Z1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please look over the information on asking questions in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and how to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Knowing what your expected result and the exact problem will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. 
You can indeed use lists to store the acceleration, velocity and position:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g=9.8
coeff=0.0001
tstep=0.9

acc=0
vel=0
pos=30000

acceleration=[acc]
velocity=[vel]
position=[pos]

while pos>=0:

    acc=g-coeff*(vel**2)
    acceleration.append(acc)   

    pos=pos-vel*tstep
    position.append(pos)   

    vel=vel+acc*tstep  
    velocity.append(vel)

plt.plot(velocity)
plt.xlabel('time [s]')
plt.ylabel('velocity [m/s]')
```

In the above code example, I multiplied the squared velocity by an arbitrary coefficient, as I did not know what value you wanted to use for mass m.

A few remarks:

- In my opinion, there is no need to take the absolute value of the velocity in the expression of the acceleration. The velocity should be greater or equal than zero, therefore you should have V=abs(V).
- There is no need to define and update time T here, as you do not use it later in your code.

Hope this helps.